# How I can resolve : dictionary and list work

Tags: python

Code:

```
dictionary = {'x_position': 25, 'y_position': 9, 'speed': ['fast', 'medium', 'slow']}

# Change the position
mouse = str(input('Enter your mouse speed\t'))

for i in dictionary['speed']:
    print(i)
    if i == mouse:
        increment = 10
    elif i == mouse:
        increment = 5
    elif i == mouse:
        increment = 2
    else:
        increment = 0

dictionary['x_position'] = dictionary['x_position'] + int(increment)
dictionary['y_position'] = dictionary['y_position'] + int(increment)

print('The X Position is : ' + str(dictionary['x_position']) + ' and The Y Position is :' + str(dictionary['y_position']))
```

I would like to know why I cannot increment the position even  the `input == #dictionary['speed']`

any suggestion

Comment: All the `if` and `elif` conditions are the same. You are probably falling back to `else` and your `increment` is always `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You're making this a little harder than it needs to be. Your loop won't stop just because the input is `fast` it will go on and check if mouse is `medium` and `slow` and then set the increment to `0` id not. But a loop is not really the best way to do this. Instead make the speed a dictionary that maps input to values. Then you can just look them up. If you use `.get()` for the lookup you can set the default to zero if something else is input.

Here's an example:

```
d = {
    'x_position': 25, 
    'y_position': 9, 
    'speed': {'fast':10, 'medium':5, 'slow':2}
}

# Change the position
mouse = input('Enter your mouse speed\t')

increment = d['speed'].get(mouse, 0) # lookup increment
d['x_position'] += increment
d['y_position'] += increment

print('The X Position is: {} and The Y Position is:{}'.format(d['x_position'], d['y_position']))
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question, you want the user to enter a speed (fast, medium, or slow) and then that speed would impact the increment of the x and y positions? If I am understanding that correctly, then a change to your code to make that work could look like:

```
    dictionary = {'x_position': 25, 'y_position': 9, 'speed': ['fast', 'medium', 'slow']}
    # Change the position
    mouse = str(input('Enter your mouse speed (fast, medium, or slow)\t'))

    for speed in dictionary:
        if mouse == 'fast':
            increment = 10
        elif mouse == 'medium':
            increment = 5
        elif mouse == 'slow':
            increment = 2
        else:
            increment = 0

    dictionary['x_position'] = dictionary['x_position'] + int(increment)
    dictionary['y_position'] = dictionary['y_position'] + int(increment)

    print('The X Position is : ' + str(dictionary['x_position']) + ' and The Y Position is :' + str(dictionary['y_position']))
```

For example now if you execute this code and enter "fast" for the input, the output would be: "The X Position is : 35 and The Y Position is :19"

Comment: Why do you need to loop over the dictionary if the speeds are hard-coded into the tests in the loop? (i.e you're not using `speed` at all in the loop).